# Display rtsp stream in android app

Tags: android, rtsp, live-streaming

I want to make an android app in which i want to display the rtsp live stream from ip camera.I tried with Mediaplayer api but it is showing errors. if anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        i.setType("video/*");
        startActivity(i);
```

Comment: i tried with this.... mVideoView.setVideoPath("rtsp link");
mVideoView.start();......it dint work